# How to make a hardisk from a portable hardisk?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, router, external-hard-drive, home-networking

I have a acer 500 gb portable harddisk and want to convert it in to a network hard disk. so that i dont have to carry it along and also not to keep my computer power on for whole day. I have iball baton router. any suggestion how can i make it

Answer (score 0):

You have two basic options:

- Buy a professionally made NAS like [QNAP](http://www.qnap.com/), [Synology](http://www.synology.com/) etc. and either dismount the harddrive from the portable case or connect the portable drive as it is to the NAS.
- Build your own NAS for example using [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi). There are tutorials on the Internet: [How to Turn a Raspberry Pi into a Low-Power Network Storage Device](http://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/), [R-Pi NAS](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_NAS). There you will (most probably) connect the portable drive as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would likely be to get a Network Attached Storage appliance (NAS), remove your Acer hard drive from its chassis, and put it into your NAS.

Considering that the hard drive you are currently in possession of is likely a 2.5 inch drive, you would need some sort of over-chassis for insertion into your NAS, as most all NAS Appliances only support full sized drives. Due to this, it may be more advantageous to create your own appliance with a board such as the Raspberry Pi (again, as Pabouk mentioned) as you would not need to rig up a chassis for your NAS, let alone pay the 150+ dollars that NAS Appliances usually cost.

This brings in another concern- *The amount of money you would like or need to spend.* Most all NAS solutions are generally quite pricey; mostly due to the fact that they are easy to manage, have long lives, and are generally more stable than a home-made NAS appliances. Essentially, with price comes quality.

Purchasing a pre-built NAS would also be a better solution if you are not adept with computers and the assembly of them. Appliances like [this one](http://www.memoryexpress.com/Products/MX45702) are as simple as plugging into the wall and into a router, and pressing an on button- the device does *everything else* for you, and this can be quite advantageous. Again, though, this would require the addition of a chassis adapter into the device, which is generally not a good alternative to a device actually designed for the size of drive you have.

Of course, I am answering under the assumption your current drive is a small-scale 2.5 inch drive- if it were, say, a 3.5 inch drive then you would have no problem at all fitting it into an everyday NAS appliance.

Whatever the path you choose in terms of what solution you are going to use, I will say that it should generally be easy to configure your device with your router. Simply get a regular CAT6 or CAT5 cable and plug it from your appliance into one of the LAN ports of your router, and you'll be all set. Any device on your network that supports network storage locations (pretty much all Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux operating systems) should be able to view and open the files on your NAS, and if you network devices such as Smart-TVs, Phones, Tablets, etc. this should open up even more cababilities of your NAS.